# What are "confirmations"when selling Bitcoins?

Tags: transactions

Bitcoin confirmation. When and how do I make a conformation of a sale. Do I receive a emaIl from you when I sell.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are transacting with the bitcoins. If you are on a website like coinbase and selling or sending coins. You might get an email from them depending if you have notifications on. This is a 3rd party that holds your bitcoin and has setup email system for it. But if you have your own Bitcoin wallet that is not controlled by a 3rd party company, you won't be getting any emails as the "bitcoin blockchain" isn't a 3rd party company.